# Should tags only apply to on-topic aspects of a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is [a suggested edit](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8341) to apply the [windows](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag to [Formatting a 720K floppy disk over USB fails with Windows 10](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5733/278). Windows 10 isn't on-topic, but it *is* Windows…

Should we apply tags about non-retro parts of on-topic questions?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it needs to be added.

Tags are not qualifier of content regarding on/off-topic criteria/sections, but indicators to find related questions when searching. Thus **applying them should go strictly by question content**. In this case Win10 is no doubt a Windows - no matter how much we like it or not - and the tag needs to be applied.

Comment: I would agree with this.  Accessing retro equipment from modern equipment is on-topic, so we should apply the Windows tag in this case.